# Streamlining OTA testing on local network

Tags: iphone, testing, ipa, ota

I need to allow an iPad to quickly install an IPA saved on a local network. The solution I am using today is pretty cumbersome:

1. Create IPA
2. Uninstall previous version from iPad
3. Restart iTunes, if running
4. Drag new IPA over to iTunes
5. Sync
6. Populate the documents folder of the app with large test files which was deleted because of uninstall.

I tried several other ways, including the obvious just drag over the new IPA directly to iTunes without uninstalling it first, but the updated IPA is just ignored.

(Also, I cannot install over a cable from Monodevelop directly, as I am on a Windows machine and the remote controlled Mac doing the actually compilation is not physically anywhere near me. We also have other testers who need to install the IPA as well.)

Is there a faster way to do this? I am doing frequent benchmarks of my app, and this long testing cycle is seriously slowing everything down.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 4+, you can accomplish this with wireless distribution:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW2

Comment: In particular, make a copy of [this](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/) index.php script (assuming you're using PHP of course.. if not, then make a similar page in your server-side language of choice), and tick `Save for Enterprise Distribution` when making the `.ipa`, providing a URL of `_URL_` (it'll be modified by index.php to match the URL you are deploying it from at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PHP you can have a look at my shell script that will help you generate all the necessary .plist files and links:

https://github.com/sveinungkb/ios-ota-buddy